# How <a4j:commandButton> works on RichFaces 4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf, commandbutton

People,

I have an application with RichFaces 3 that works perfectly and i'm trying change to RichFaces 4.

The problem that could not solve involves the use of the .

On RichFaces 3, the below code works:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="button test" action="#{bean.executeAction()}" reRender="myForm"/>
```

I try change to

```
<a4j:commanButton value="button teste" action="#{bean.executeAction()}" render="myForm"/>
```

or

```
<a4j:commanButton value="button teste" actionListener="#{bean.executeAction()}" render="myForm"/>
```

or n others possibilities, however, nothing work.

Help please.

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing works"? is there any exception message? is the action method executed?

Comment: I assume it is a typo in this post: a4j:commanDbutton  <-- Your tries mis the 'd' ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add the 'execute'.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Button" type="submit" 
                   id="button_1" render="myForm"
                   execute="@form" 
                   action="#{bean.executeAction()}" />
```

This button works for me at least